# Getting CppUnit to read application class on netbeans 7.2

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-7, cppunit

I am learning C++ and CppUnit at the same time, using netbeans 7.2.

I create the following file

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
class Subtract{
public:
    int minus(int a, int b){
        return a-b;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    return 0;
}
```

And then I right-click to generate the following cppunit test file

```
#include "newtestclass.h"


CPPUNIT_TEST_SUITE_REGISTRATION(newtestclass);

newtestclass::newtestclass() {
}

newtestclass::~newtestclass() {
}

void newtestclass::setUp() {
}

void newtestclass::tearDown() {
}

int Subtract::minus(int a, int b);

void newtestclass::testMinus() {
    int a=89;
    int b=55;
    Subtract subtract;
    int result = subtract.minus(a, b);
    CPPUNIT_ASSERT_EQUAL(34,result);
}
```

When I try to run the test, it gives the following errors

```
g++    -c -g -I. -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/tests/newtestclass.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/tests/newtestclass.o tests/newtestclass.cpp
tests/newtestclass.cpp:25: error: 'Subtract' has not been declared
tests/newtestclass.cpp: In member function 'void newtestclass::testMinus()':
tests/newtestclass.cpp:30: error: 'Subtract' was not declared in this scope
tests/newtestclass.cpp:30: error: expected `;' before 'subtract'
tests/newtestclass.cpp:31: error: 'subtract' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/tests/tests/newtestclass.o] Error 1
make: *** [.build-tests-impl] Error 2
```

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C++, the convention is to declare the classes and functions in a header file (.h file) and implement them in the source file (.cpp file).

Your Subtract.h file (declarations) should have only this:

```
class Subtract {
public:
    int minus(int a, int b);
};
```

Your Subtract.cpp file (implementation) should have this:

```
#include "Subtract.h"

int Subtract::minus(int a, int b)
{
    return a-b;
}
```

Then you #include "Subtract.h" in your newtestclass.cpp file.

Comment: The books and online tutorials I am using don't divide between header and cpp files. Is there a way to combine the .h and .cpp files in netbeans?

Comment: Best practice is not to combine them. The .h file defines the interface, it declares the types, and is the stuff to be shared with everyone wanting to use your class. The .cpp file is the specifics of how it is done, and is of no concern to the other modules. Don't try to mix the two together at this stage in your learning. Instead, try to discover why the distinction is important.